# How to create a function that changes characters of a string?

Tags: c, string

I'm new to coding and I've been studying C recently. Basically, I wanted to create the following function, which modifies every string element:

```
char *stralt(char *s, char ch)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i!='\0'; i++)
        s[i] = ch;
    return s;
}
```

And when I try to use it on int main(), like this:

```
int main()

{
    printf("%s", stralt("test",'x'));   
}
```

The prompt shows "test" instead of "xxxx". What is wrong with this code and how could it work properly?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. In C you aren't allowed to modify a string literal. Instead of passing a string literal, use an array: `char string[] = "test"; printf("%s", stralt(string,'x'));`

Comment: `"test"` is a literal string. Literal strings are really arrays of characters, and are ***not*** allowed to be modified. Attempting to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong: `for (i=0; i!='\0'; i++)` What you want is `for (i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)` WIth your condition that loop will never be executed as `i!=0` is false when you start iterating

Comment: In addition to preceding comment: I personally consider operating on pointers more convenient: `for(; *s; ++s) { *s = ch; }` – if you prefer continuing on the index variable I'd move its declaration into the loop header to limit its scope to the loop: `for(int i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {...}`

Comment: @Gerhardh I still have the same problem by doing that, prompt keeps showing "test" rather than "xxxx".

Comment: You must fix both issues to make it work.

Comment: It worked! Ssometimes it's hard to find a silly mistake and it's better to have someone from outside looking at it. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems, one of which isn't apparent because the other doesn't allow it to occur.

---

You have:

```
for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
```

Here, you compare the value of `i` against `'\0'`, which is `0`. Since `i` is `0` at the beginning of the `for` loop, the condition `i != '\0'` will be false, and the loop will exit before entering the body.

It seems that you meant to say:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

---

The other problem is that you're trying to modify a string literal. `s[i] = ch;` is invalid if `s` points to a string literal, as it does in your example.

Instead, you have to have a modifiable array of characters. This could be accomplished by modifying your `main` like:

```
int main()
{
    char test_str[] = "test";
    printf("%s", stralt(test_str, 'x'));   
}
```

Comment: One comment on the code style is that `++i` is generally preferred to `i++` as a `for` loop iteration expression.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now. Appreciate the tip also!

Comment: @Gauss-00 be aware that C has no real string type like other languages. "Strings" in C are merely pointers and if you're not aware of that, many things can (and will) go wrong.

Comment: Not _quite_ accurate. Attempting to modify a string literal is not forbidden per se, but rather invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ThomasJager "++i is generally preferred to i++" --> note the the C-spec does not follow that style. It used `i++`. _generally preferred_ needs objective support to be more than an opinion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky <"Strings" in C are merely pointers> is amiss.  C lib defines _strings_ as "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.", not as a pointer.  C also has _string literals_.  They also are not pointers.